# Their luxurious lifestyle/lifestyles

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

> I'm interested in celebrities' luxurious lifestyle/lifestyles.

Should *lifestyle* be plural because *celebrities* is plural? Or maybe it should be singular if those celebrities only have one lifestyle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be plural because each celebrity has their own lifestyle. Replace "lifestyle" with "car" and it should be clearer:

> *I'm interested in celebrities' luxurious **car**.

That sentence suggests that all celebrities share one single luxurious car, which is nonsense. The same applies to abstract nouns like "lifestyle".

It would make more sense if you referred instead to "*the celebrity lifestyle*", which refers generically to a lifestyle of luxurious parties, lots of drug use, buying lots of expensive things, high fashion, avoiding paparazzi and so on.

It's worth noting here that not all celebrities live the celebrity lifestyle, and not all people who live the celebrity lifestyle are celebrities. So it depends on whether the writer of this sentence is interested in that lifestyle, or in the possibly mundane lifestyle of individual celebrities.

Comment: I don't think replacing "lifestyle" with "car" is warranted here. "Car" is a countable noun, while "lifestyle" can be countable or uncountable.

Comment: @PPH I don't think "lifestyle" can be an uncountable noun. Singular yes, but not uncountable. Can you give an example?

Comment: [Oxford Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/lifestyle?q=lifestyle) disagrees with you.

Comment: OK, but in this context, it's clearly countable.

Comment: Your stated that you didn't think "lifestyle" could be uncountable and asked for proof, which I provided. As to whether it is "clearly" countable in the present context, I have already given my opinion in my answer. I rest my case.

Answer (score 3):

Both can be correct. It depends on whether you are thinking of the general lifestyle celebrities have or the particularities of each celebrity's lifestyle.

In fact, a Google search brings in the following:
"celebrities' luxurious lifestyle" 121 results
"celebrities' luxurious lifestyles" 63 results

Comment: Ah, nice.  I 'd +1'ed the answer @gotube gave, but now I'm also +1'ing yours. Now you point it out, it's obvious that the singular general "lifestyle" does fit. That said, the fact that I upvoted gotube's does indicate that, for me at least, the plural "lifestyles" is the more immediate interpretation; so much so that If wanted to convey the singular meaning, I reckon that instead of, *"I'm interested in celebrities' luxurious lifestyle"*, I'd go for, *"I'm interested in the luxurious lifestyle of celebrities."*